# How to add authbind to my Play Framework start script (generated with "play stage")?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt, upstart

I'm using `authbind` to allow my Play Framework app to bind to port 80 when run as a non-root user.

My target/start script needs to look like this for it to work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

exec authbind --deep java $@ -cp "`dirname $0`/staged/*" play.core.server.NettyServer `dirname $0`/..
```

At the moment I'm manually modifying this generated file (urgh!). I can't find an elegant way to get `play stage` to automatically insert the `authbind --deep` before the java command.

This `target/start` script is launched from an Upstart script, and I have tried putting `authbind --deep` in there, but this doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust your project/Build.scala file:

```
lazy val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    playStage <<= (playStage, baseDirectory) map {(stageCommand, baseDir) =>
      val content = """#!/usr/bin/env sh
                      |
                      |exec authbind --deep java $@ -cp "`dirname $0`/staged/*" play.core.server.NettyServer `dirname $0`/..""".stripMargin
      IO.write(baseDir / "target" / "start", content)
      stageCommand
    }
  )
```

This overrides the play stage task and writes a custom start script file.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I tried this but got:

 not found: value playStage
[error]   playStage <<= (playStage, baseDirectory) map { (stageCommand, baseDir) =>
[error]   ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed

I'm using SBT 0.12.1 and Play 2.1.0 with SBT plugin 2.1.0. Could the command be different for me? I've searched the API and found playStage amongst sbt.PlayCommands but can't figure out how to use it within play.Project.

Comment: I cannot reproduce you error, but you can checkout my project: https://github.com/schleichardt/stackoverflow-answers/tree/so16110908

Comment: Thank you very much for posting that. I was simply missing "import play.Project._"

Comment: could you advise on how I might migrate the above solution to Play 2.2? Seems they've changed the packager